# Proving group action on $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F})$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I got asked to prove by conjugation $P\cdot A=PAP^{-1}$ that $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F})\curvearrowright \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ where $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F})$ is the general liner group.

I'm not sure that I understand what does it mean to prove by conjugation. I know the theorm behind the $\curvearrowright$ operator, but I'm not sure how to connect it with $P\cdot A=PAP^{-1}$.

The theorm I understand: let $G$ be a group and $X$ is a set. Then a (left) group action $\phi$ of $G$ on $X$ is a function:

$$G\times X \to X:(g,x) \to \phi (g,x)$$

In order to show the theorm we should prove identity and compatibility. I just don't understand how.

Comment: $PA$ is the definition of the action, not a matrix product.

Comment: What do you mean with the "theorem behind the $\curvearrowright$ operator"?

Comment: At present, this question is unclear, so, regrettably, I've voted to close it.

Comment: Please check out my edit

Comment: You mean you want to prove that the conjugation formula you gave acutally defines an action of the genral linear group on the groups of square matrices, is that it?

Comment: In any case, writing $PA = PAP^{-1}$ makes no sense. You could put something like $P.A=PAP^{-1}$ or ${}^PA=PAP^{-1}$.

Comment: @Derek Holt you are right, I have edit my question. A.Rod, I wrote the question as it shown I the book. Im not sure either how to understand it.

Comment: Just check that $(g.h).A=g.(h.A)$ and $1.A=A$ which should not be too hard.

Comment: The phrasing of the question is basically nonsense. The best (and only) sensible interpretation I can think of is as A Rod points out: prove conjugation is indeed a group action.